# Sphinx Docker Deployment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-sphinx

I'm trying to create documentation website with docker-compose. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.rizzonicola.com/posts/sphinx-docker/). In local, I can run it successfully but when I try run container in server it returns me this error:

```
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.430819779Z [sphinx-autobuild] > sphinx-build -b html /etc/Sphinx/source /etc/Sphinx/build
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.807214119Z 
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.807251454Z Application error:
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.807257159Z Cannot find source directory (/etc/Sphinx/source)
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.867591050Z Command exited with exit code: 2
docs_1     | 2022-09-06T14:34:44.867628073Z The server will continue serving the build folder, but the contents being served are no longer in sync with the documentation sources. Please fix the cause of the error above or press Ctrl+C to stop the server.
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /etc/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/Sphinx/build

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip make git
RUN pip install git+https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx && \
    pip install sphinx-autobuild

CMD sphinx-autobuild -b html --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 /etc/Sphinx/source /etc/Sphinx/build
COPY /doc/ /etc/Sphinx/source
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  docs:
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/my_username/${IMAGE}
    container_name: docs
    build: .docker
    volumes:
        - ./doc:/etc/Sphinx/source
    ports:
      - 8100:80
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml` in the server:

```yaml
docs:
  image: registry.digitalocean.com/my_username/docs
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - 8100:80
```

My folder structure is:

```
docs/
├─ .docker/
│  ├─ dev.env
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ prod.env
├─ doc/
│  ├─ conf.py
│  ├─ index.rst
│  ├─ getting_started.rst
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ README.md
```

I tried to copy files in `doc` folder to `/etc/Sphinx/source` but it returns me this error:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/doc" not found: not found
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say `I tried to copy files in doc folder to /etc/Sphinx/source but it returns me this error:` what is the command you actually run

Comment: Last line in my Dockerfile. I added that after error. I tried different variations like `./doc`, `/doc`, `doc/` but still gives "not found" error.